# Counter Metrics for Rest Api's in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, performancecounter

What would be the best approach to count how many times an API is being triggered with its successful/failure response in spring boot.

What I have in my mind is using a post construct to start a new thread when application comes up and when an api is being called and then using a counter service for each new unique request to count how many api's is being triggered by that particular request and how many of them are successful or failed.

Recommend some new approaches if you guys have any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to create if from scratch, you can simply use Spring Boot Actuator that has this feature built-in. Just add following dependency to your project:

**pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Actuator exposes e.g. [`/metrics`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html) endpoint and here you can find a counters for all responses - each counter starts with `counter.status.{{status_code}}.{{endpoint}}`.

For example, I have simple demo application with `/hello` endpoint. Any time I call this endpoint metric `counter.status.200.hello` will be increased. When I access `/metrics` endpoint I can see something like:

```
{
  "mem": 586013,
  "mem.free": 324496,
  "processors": 8,
  "instance.uptime": 144496,
  "uptime": 149950,
  "systemload.average": 0.52,
  "heap.committed": 522240,
  "heap.init": 251904,
  "heap.used": 197743,
  "heap": 3580928,
  "nonheap.committed": 64960,
  "nonheap.init": 2496,
  "nonheap.used": 63773,
  "nonheap": 0,
  "threads.peak": 42,
  "threads.daemon": 25,
  "threads.totalStarted": 54,
  "threads": 27,
  "classes": 8938,
  "classes.loaded": 8938,
  "classes.unloaded": 0,
  "gc.ps_scavenge.count": 8,
  "gc.ps_scavenge.time": 54,
  "gc.ps_marksweep.count": 2,
  "gc.ps_marksweep.time": 65,
  "gauge.response.star-star.favicon.ico": 1,
  "counter.status.200.star-star": 2,
  "counter.status.304.star-star": 2,
  "counter.status.200.metrics.name": 2,
  "counter.status.200.star-star.favicon.ico": 5,
  "gauge.response.star-star": 3,
  "gauge.response.hello": 5,
  "gauge.response.metrics.name": 3,
  "counter.status.200.hello": 2,
  "counter.status.404.metrics.name": 1,
  "httpsessions.max": -1,
  "httpsessions.active": 0,
  "datasource.primary.active": 0,
  "datasource.primary.usage": 0
}
```

I can also access single metric, e.g. `/metrics/counter.status.200.hello` which returns only:

```
{
  "counter.status.200.hello": 2
}
```

By default `/metrics` endpoint is secured. For your local dev you can turn it of by adding:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

to your *application.yml* or

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

to *application.properties* if you use that one.

Comment: But let's say I have 1000 of  unique customers for which this hello api is triggered. How will I know that for a particular customer, how many hello are triggered.

Comment: @Mangla Do we need to disable spring security to implement views count using Actuator?