# Number of times REST API was called

Tags: java, json, rest, api

If I have a HTTP REST API : `example /getCount`

**Sample Code**

```
@RestController
public class CountController {
    long count = 0;
    @Getmapping("/getCount")
    public long getCount(){
        count++; // Here is the problem, how to keep the latest count if the API was hit by multiple Application/clients
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Problem Description**: Every time any app/system call the above mentioned API, count will be increased by 1 and the caller  entity can get the exact number of hit.

**Condition**: Its a open API.Need guidance how to achieve it.
This is the only problem statement I am having

Comment: In case of a system restart, the count would be reset to 0

Comment: Yes..It will .But we have to keep the older count and next time any App hit the URL it will get the updated.This will also need to take care.

Comment: If you need count, after app restart then you should store count some where in file or database.

Comment: [Microprofile Metrics Counter](https://microprofile.io/project/eclipse/microprofile-metrics/spec/src/main/asciidoc/rest-endpoints.adoc) could be fitting.

Comment: do you need to increase count when /getCount URL hit? or every request you need to increase count?

Comment: You can use java atomic Util classes, if it as a single jvm instance.

Comment: did you try using static type,  if counter is common for all clients and counter will restart to 0 on server restart.?

Comment: @rahulnikhare see my updated answer :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use static type if you want counter behavior as follows

- Counter is common for all clients calling APIs.
- Counter will restart to 0 as soon as server will restart.

```java
@RestController
public class CountController {
    static long count = 0;
    @Getmapping("/getCount")
    public long getCount(){
        count++; // Here is the problem, how to keep the latest count if the API was hit by multiple Application/clients
        return count;
    }
}
```

If You want different counter for all client or want to hold counter value even if server is shutdown or restart then you need to use DB to store counter.

Comment: `count` field doesn't have to be `static` field - it should work as long as `CountController` is scoped as `singleton`

Answer (score 1):

As spring provides `singleton` scope by default for its beans - your current code should work even for multiple requests UNLESS app gets **restarted**.

**An alternative solution: using [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-getting-started)**,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And add `@Timed` annotation to a request-handling method.

Now you can get statistics through http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests

**Edit - To provide multi-client request count**

After aggregating and revising your question and different comments - It seems you are trying to achieve each users request-count. I believe you need to use `HttpServletRequest` to track clients IP address so that requests can be distinguished. And as far as I know about `Open API` - It doesn't provide such method definition, so you need to program explicitly.

Your modified code should look like this,

```
@RestController
public class CountController {

    private static Map<String, Long> CLIENT_REQUEST_COUNT = new HashMap<>();

    @Getmapping("/getCount")
    public long getCount(HttpServletRequest request){

        String client = request.getRemoteAddr();

        if(Objects.nonNull(CLIENT_REQUEST_COUNT.get(client))) {
            long newCount = CLIENT_REQUEST_COUNT.get(client) + 1;
            CLIENT_REQUEST_COUNT.put(client, newCount);
            return newCount;
        }

        CLIENT_REQUEST_COUNT.put(client, 1);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If you want to map your request-count with your client-object(if you have such object) other than using IP address - you need to retrieve current user and map them respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides a nice capability through AtomicInteger. This is a thread-safe object and you can rely on to increment whenever your counter method is called.

### First:

You need to define your Resource class as Singleton and initiate the AtomicInteger.

```
private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
```

### Second:

You need to add the following code inside your rest method to increment the current counter by one. This will be automatically taken care by the following method,

```
count.incrementAndGet();
```

### Finally:

When you need to get the current counter you can have a REST method to get the details like below,

```
@GetMapping("count")
public int getCount() {
    return this.count.get();
}
```

I hope this would clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is incomplete information but still try to answer this question in my way.
**Do you need to increase count when /getCount URL hit andcontinue counter after application restart.?**
If yes then simply make one database table with count column. Load this value into one variable while starting app and increase this value everytime.

But I dont this you want to do this!

**Do you need to increase count on every URL request but dont want previous history when application restart/shutdown?**
In this case *SPRING Actuator* is good way to implement. You do not need to write code for this. 
Use Shekhar Rai answer or [Counter Metrics for Rest Api's in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239614/counter-metrics-for-rest-apis-in-springboot)

**Do you need to increase count on every URL request, also continue counter after application restart.**
In this case, make database table for keep maintain counter because you need counter continue after restart application.
In filter, create small thread to make database hit increase this counter. Thread because this task is not high priority so should not interfere in main task.

Comment: But let's say I have 1000 of unique customers for which this api is triggered. How will I know how many times it is triggered

Comment: Means you need to track each users hit count?

Comment: if you need to track each unique user hit count then make table("user","count"). 
In filter get session and from session fetch user. If user is not registered or in your system then get IP address and store count against IP address.