# How to find total no of times api endpoint is been called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

IS there any way to count how many times the endpoint is been called by the client. and return them the no. of times endpoint called?

In mky api user can create store url with id(pk, auto increase) and user can search for the url. at the same time I have code that can able to redirect user to particular url if user manually put it over url for ex - localhost:8080/findurlbyid?id=3 --> then user will get redirect

How can I give this link to the user in response?

my controller code ->

```java
@GetMapping("/redirectByUrl")
public ResponseEntity<?> redirectByUrl(Integer id) throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Location", sortnerService.redirectByUrl(id));
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
}
```

Sorter Model class contain -> int id, String unl; and sortnerservice having some functions and repo is extending jpaRepository Can any one help me out in this
One more thing right now I am responding with the url that client has entered, I want to return the entire Url like  => localhost:8080/findbyurl?id=3 as the response if user search for id no.3

Comment: I think what you are looking for is handled already in Spring-boot actuator module. Here is the example for it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59588180/5823739 (Implementation for count of API calls)

Answer (score 2):

Your question detail is very vague. From the topic itself I would recommend using a Singleton to keep track of the number of times your Api has been called via a setter then just call a getter method from the Singleton to retrieve the current count.

```
 public class ApiFetchCountSingleton{

 private static ApiFetchCountSingleton INSTANCE = null;
 private int fetchCount;

 public static ApiFetchCountSingleton getInstance(){

    if(INSTANCE == null){
        synchronized(ApiFetchCountSingleton.class){
        INSTANCE = new ApiFetchCountSingleton();
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
 }

 public void setFetchCount(int count){
    this.fetchCount = count;
 }
 public int getFetchCount(){
    return fetchCount;

 }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
 @GetMapping("/redirectByUrl")
 public ResponseEntity<?> redirectByUrl(Integer id) throws Exception {

    ApiFetchCountSingleton singleton = ApiFetchCountSingleton.getInstance(); // get Class Instance
    int fetchCount = singleton.getFetchCount();  // get last fetch Count
    singleton.setFetchCount(fetchCount + 1); // increment by 1 and set new count value
    System.out.println("FETCH COUNT "+singleton.getFetchCount()); // Display new count value
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Location", sortnerService.redirectByUrl(id));
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
 }
```

Comment: It will be nice if you have Atomic Integer

Answer (score 1):

You can create static variable and increment the count on each call. Also you can use this variable anywhere in your code even to return the value.

Comment: Thanks How can I send url as response to the client , My api is nothing but having two fields id (auto inc and primary key) and url, so clinet can add url fetch all urls and redirect to some url that are saved already of now client needs to write it manually in the url like localhost:8080/allurl?id=3 what i want is to response back this entire url as long as client save a new url in the db ? can you help me in this.. how this can be done

Comment: In responseEntity you can add a body which will be the string you want to return. That will help you to return what you want. If you want to enhance you can create your own pojo class and can send this object as body

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do it like making another variable counter in pojo class and while hitting the endpoint /getUrl I can be able to increase that count variable...